# How to change template in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular, so perhaps what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

The layout I'm trying to achieve would look like the following:

[image: Example Layout]

This is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9rMIZhmJQaqg2K3k7tH8?p=preview) example which I've been trying to update with no success.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []).
controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp("http://www.filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rows=5&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}").
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data
    })
});
```

```css
.card {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-repeat="user in users" class="row">
            <div class="card">
            {{user.fname}} {{user.lname}} 
            </div
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the criteria for when you'd split a div into two?

Comment: Could you fill the mock-up layout with data? It is hard to imagine why the first three rows and the last row should span the whole width but not the fourth row.

Comment: It's not obvious from this data, but the data I will be working with will occasionally be missing images or descriptions, in these cases I want to offer a different presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will highly depend on your dataset and how it comes back. You will most likely need to presort it or do some kind of processing so that the items that you want to display as 'half' cards are always in pairs at least or you will have random gaps.

Here is the plunker with just the concept of having half and full sized cards. http://plnkr.co/edit/RbUyIzUbxhg7gJmUfYO5

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" class="row">
    <div class="card" ng-class="user.half ? 'half' : 'full'">
      {{user.fname}} {{user.lname}}
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
```

I suggest you split them so that all full cards are grouped together and all half sized cards are grouped together. Its possible to interlace them but like I said before you will have to manipulate the array first so that they come in pairs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for ng-class.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" class="row">
        <div ng-class="yourExpression ? 'halfCard' : 'card'>
        {{user.fname}} {{user.lname}} 
        </div>
    </div>
```

If yourExpression is true it will use halfCard as the class, if its false it will use card.

Answer (score 1):

You could have all cards have `display:inline-block`. That way, they go side by side. Then in your data, indicate when it is a full or a half. When you use `ng-repeat`, use that indicator to tell the template whether to use a full or a half. A full would have a width of 100%, a half would be 50%. The 50% ones will line up side by side, while the full ones will always go under due to size constraints of the container.